# How do I enable https only on certain pages with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

I have an ecommerce site, and I want to enable https only on the ecommerce section of the site located at https://mysite.com/buy

Since all of the links on my pages are relative, when someone visits http://mysite.com and clicks on Buy, they are taken to http://mysite.com/buy

Also, if they visit https://mysite.com/buy and click on a link to another page, they are taken to https://mysite.com.

The reason I want https only on that one section is because I have external elements (i.e. Google Maps, Youtube, Twitter, etc) that cannot be sent over https.

Is there a way with htaccess that I can make the /buy directory force https, but every other page force http?

Edit:
In case anyone is interested, I was able to solve this using PHP. I would still prefer an htaccess solution, but this will work for now:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") {
    if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"buy") === false) {
        Header("Location: http://$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# redirect for http /buy page
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^buy/?$ https://mysite.com/buy [R=301,QSA,L,NE]

# redirect for https non /buy pages
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/buy [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L,NE]
```

`R=301` will redirect with https status 301
`L` will make last rule
`NE` is for no escaping query string
`QSA` will append your existing query parameters
`NC` is for ignore case comparison

`$1` is your REQUEST_URI

Comment: You can simplify `RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L,NE]` to `RewriteRule (.*) http://mysite.com$1 [R=301,QSA,L,NE]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have hands on experience, but from what I see, it looks like the htaccess configuration file should impact only the files in the folder in which the file is stored.

So you should be able to do something like this:

http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/force-ssl-htaccess.html

And put it in the /buy folder of your site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that /buy is a rewritten URL, so the /buy folder doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

If your web page is hosted on `9001` port  just enable any port on your linux box and make these changes in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`.Then set your Listen Port to `9002` and create SSL certificate and key and put following configuration in your *httpd.conf* file

```
Listen 9001
<VirtualHost *:9001>
ServerAdmin root@localhost
DocumentRoot /mnt/work/httpd
<Directory "/mnt/work/httpd">
Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>
  SSLEngine On
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/www.test.example.com.key
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/www.test.example.com.crt
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.test.example.com:9002%{REQUEST_URI}
```

and your .htaccess file should look like this

```
AuthType Digest
AuthName "Protected"
AuthDigestProvider file
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthUserFile /mnt/work/httpd/digest_auth
Require user username**
```