# https on 2 forms only, all others force back to http

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https

Google has been indexing duped content. SEO nightmare...

I have two forms which need SSL.

/single

/joint

I'd like everything else to be redirected back to non ssl (http://)

I've tried various different things from the forums here, numerous times...

[How do I enable https only on certain pages with htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720463/how-do-i-enable-https-only-on-certain-pages-with-htaccess)

The first part always works, that is, https redirects to http but the  /single & /joint will redirect to index.php or the "home page"

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Try to be more clear...

With Jon's code added to the .htaccess file

https .com/other-page

redirects to http .com/other-page

But the ones that matter

https .com/single & .com/joint

Both redirect to

http .com/index.php

Here is a link to the standard Joomla .htaccess file

http://docs.joomla.org/Preconfigured_htaccess

In addition I am using rewrite rules to redirect www to non www

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^website.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

Add these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(single|joint) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^(single|joint) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

as long as the form is submitted as a GET request. The request body in a POST submission may not be included after a redirect.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Sadly, same thing... every other url redirects properly to http except /single /joint both redirect to /index.php...

Comment: @user2853053 Are you sure those rules are before *any* other rules that are in the htaccess file?

Comment: Ahah! They are not. I will do this now. Let you know. Thanks

Comment: @user2853053 make sure to clear your browser's cache

Comment: Cleared cache, same thing. If it helps I added a link to the .htaccess file in use & my custom rules